# Status 502 in Nginx

Tags: nginx, centos, centos7

I have configured Nginx on a CentOS 7 server. There I have 2 sites running, I installed the SSL certificate using Cerbot and the process was executed with no errors. There I have 2 subdomains, `x.mydomain.com` and `y.mydomain.com`

The sites that I am running correspond to applications that are running on their own ports, 9100 for one and 9200 for the second one, so I configured Nginx to redirect the petitions to the corresponding port. For example, the server block for the first application is:

```
   server {
                listen          80;
                server_name     x.mydomain.com;
                access_log      logs/mydomainX.log main;

                location / {
                        proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:9100;
                }

                listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
                ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
                ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

So, if I open in the browser `x.mydomain.com` I get status code 502 from Nginx, however, if I open directly using the IP: `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100` then I can see the site. So I must have something wrong in the Nginx configuration, what am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Status code 502 shows that nginx could connect to proxy upstream, so there is something wrong with upstream on `127.0.0.1:9100`.

If request to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100 working fine, you could change your `nginx` configuration to something like this:

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     x.mydomain.com;
    access_log      logs/mydomainX.log main;

    location / {
           proxy_pass      http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9100;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/x.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot


    if ($scheme != "https") {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

}
```

If you still want to use 127.0.0.1:9100 for proxy_pass, you should check your application, may be it not binded on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: I made it, but nothing has changed. not sure how to debug it

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova please show output from nginx `error.log`.

Comment: I had this error:" connect() to 192.168.10.106:8082 failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream" but I managed to fix it just typing `setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`